# Python Key error and repeating code in for loop

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6

I am getting an error saying
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/SSW-540/P8-hajayi.py", line 34, in 
alphabetCount[ch] += 1
KeyError: '\n'

I also noticed that the print statements are repeating and I think its probably because they are in the for loop. I do not want them to repeat.

Also the from and import in "from operator import itemgetter" and "import operator" do not glow blue like the first import. Is it because of the version of python im using? Im using python 3.6

```
from string import punctuation

from operator import itemgetter

import operator

fileName = input('Enter the file name')

file = open(fileName, 'r')

punc_translator = str.maketrans({key: None for key in punctuation})

documentFile = str(file.read()).translate(punc_translator).lower()

print(documentFile)

alphabetCount = {

"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0, "h": 0, "i": 0, "j": 0, "k": 0, "l": 0,

"m": 0, "n": 0, "o": 0, "p": 0, "q": 0, "r": 0, "s": 0, "t": 0, "u": 0, "v": 0, "w": 0, "x": 0,

"y": 0, "z": 0

}

totalWords = 0

totalDistinctWords = 0

  for ch in documentFile:
      if ch != ' ':
      alphabetCount[ch] += 1
      allWords = documentFile.split(' ')
      wordsCountDict = dict()
      for word in allWords:
         totalWords += 1
         if word in wordsCountDict.keys():
             wordsCountDict[word] += 1
         else:
             wordsCountDict[word] = 1
             totalDistinctWords += 1

     print(totalWords)
     print(totalDistinctWords)

     sortedWordsCount = sorted(wordsCountDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

     sortedCharactersCount = sorted(alphabetCount.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)

     print('The summary of document: ')

     print("Total words is: " + str(totalWords))

     print(totalDistinctWords)

     print('Most Frequent Characters:')

     print(sortedCharactersCount)

     print('Most Frequent Words:')

     print(sortedWordsCount)
```

Comment: What is your actual purpose of this task? You are directly mentioning traceback but what were you trying to achieve at first?

Comment: I stated an error that I am getting and would like the solution to that and also I would like a solution to the print statements repeating. I have them in the for loop so maybe that is the reason why but I want to know of a way where the print statements do not repeat